# sizeof('\0') null terminator as literal is four bytes but how come in string of characters it takes only one byte?

Tags: c, malloc, c-strings, sizeof, null-terminated

In c '\0' null-terminator as literal takes 4-bytes (as it's just zero internally) but how come it takes only 1-byte when used in an array of characters or string of characters? Is this compiler magic?

Does a programmer need to take special care when using dynamic memory allocation to handle null terminator size? Is the below program fine?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   printf("size of null-termination: %lu\n", sizeof('\0')); //outputs 4 bytes
   printf("size of 0: %lu\n", sizeof(0)); // outputs 4 bytes

   char *message = malloc(10);
   message[0] = 'A';
   message[1] = 'B';
   message[2] = 'C';
   message[3] = '\0'; // takes 1-byte in below memory layout(attached image)

   message[4] = 'a';
   message[5] = 'b';
   message[6] = 'c';
   message[7] = '\0'; // takes 1-byte in below memory layout(attached image)

   message[8] = 'X';
   message[9] = 'Y';

   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Plain (non-wide) character constants have type `int`, not `char`, so that is why the size of the character constant is larger than you expected.

Comment: `sizeof` produces a value of type `size_t`. The corresponding printf format specifier is `%zu`, not `%lu`.

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char('\0')));` prints "1"

Comment: `message[3]` is a single byte, therefore it's size is 1. The type of `'x'` is `int` and not `char` (which my be strange, but that's what it is), and `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner even with "%zu" it prints 4. Thanks for correction Ian Abbot

Comment: @MysteriousJack if you pass an `int` to the sizeof() operator, yes.  If you pass a `char`, it prints 1.  `\'0'` is an int, while `char('\0')` is a char.

Comment: Mysterious Jack, `message[3] = '\0'` --> left side of `=` is a `char`, right side is an `int`.  Try `message[3] = 0.0`.  Right side is a `double`.  In all cases the _value_ is zero.  The left and right side do not need to be the same type. If the right side _value_ is not encodable as a `char`, issues come up, but not for zero.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner How are able to run `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char('\0')));` ? It gives a compilation error. Are you sure we can provide a literal inside datatype like `char('\0')` to `sizeof` the operator? Note I'm using Pure GCC C compiler 11.3.0. So no C++.

Comment: @MysteriousJack you're right, I was compiling in C++ mode.  For C, `char c = '\0'; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(c));` gives the expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C opposite to C++ `'\0'` is an integer character constant that has the type `int`.

Within a character string literal such escape sequence is stored as one character.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer
> character constant containing a single character that maps to a
> single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the
> representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer

and (6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
> each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
> or literals.78) The multibyte character sequence is then used to
> initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
> sufficient to contain the sequence. **For character string literals,
> the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the
> individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence**.

Comment: Re “Within a string literal such escape sequence is stored as one character”: Within a string literal, the null terminator is just a character. The “\” in the source code for a string literal is an escape character: It escapes the usual interpretation of characters to introduce an alternative interpretation. In `"\a"`, “\” is an escape character, and the “\a” is an escape sequence. The resulting character, the alert character, is just a character.